# how to receive custom data from push notification when app is in background in android

Tags: android

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            data.add(value);
            Log.e(TAG, "key, " + key + " value " + value);

        }

        post_id = data.get(0);
        lang = data.get(1);
        link = data.get(2);

        Log.e("post_id",post_id);
        Log.e("lang",lang);
        Log.e("link",link);
    }

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}
```

when app is in background this method never called and therefore i cant receive any data when app is in background

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: It seems you are using `Notification Messages` instead of `Data Messages`. Please take a look at this link for more detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 1):

You should implement onMessageReceived() in service. So when your application in background, it's still receive this call back normal. Firebase supported all of this.

in AndroidManifest.xml declare

```
    <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
       </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

in Java code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //do receive data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null)
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when sending the data add these two attributes    `'ttl' => 3600,  'content_available' => true`

e.g.

```
return Curl::to('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send')
            ->withHeader('Authorization: key=' . env('FIREBASE_KEY'))
            ->withHeader('Content-Type: application/json')
            ->withData(['to' => $firebase_token, 'data' => $data, 'ttl' => 3600,  'content_available' => true ])
            ->asJson(true)
            ->post();
```

this helped me before.

then this should work

```
int someArg = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get(AdminCommands.KEY_SOME_ARG ));
```